# I'm managing SQLite, MySQL and PostgreSQL databases and want a tool for this locally

Tags: mac, mysql, database, postgresql, sqlite

I develop web applications on Mac OSX in SQLite, MySQL and PostgreSQL and these are then put on the webserver. I want to be able to take the brunt out of looking at the terminal locally when dealing with these databases - is there any software available (free or otherwise) that can handle all three of these database technologies in a GUI for the Mac that is actually decent and worth it?

Answer (score 1):

Navicat is king, but does it do SQLite...I am not sure

Comment: SQLite is the problem. Navicat premium will handle PostgreSQL and MySQL (as well as Oracle) but not SQLite - http://www.navicat.com/en/products/navicat_premium/premium_overview.html you would need a separate app for SQLite like Base - http://menial.co.uk/software/base/

Answer (score 0):

You could just use any SQL tool that can handle JDBC connections (such as any of the various Java SQL tools). All three DBMS have JDBC drivers.

See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644893/recommendation-for-jdbc-sql-client-tool

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RazorSQL](http://razorsql.com/).

I'm looking for something a bit better/cheaper than this, but haven't found it so far.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use FREE tool - Valentina Studio, it works as with SQLite, so with postgreSQL and mySQL/mariaDB http://www.valentina-db.com/en/valentina-studio-overview

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Generally we like answers on the site to be able to stand on their own - Links are great, but if that link ever breaks the answer should have enough information to still be helpful. Please consider editing your answer to include more detail. See the [FAQ](http://www.superuser.com/faq) for more info.